# Passing GLSL array parameters with more than one size

Tags: glsl

I defined a GLSL function that calculates the average of an array of numbers, but this function is "overloaded" to work with arrays that have more than one size. Here, the same function is defined twice with a different parameter:

```
float average(float[4] array) {
   float sum = 0.0;
   for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    sum += array[i];
   }
   return sum/float(array.length());
}

//this is redundant: the same function is defined with a different size parameter
float average(float[5] array) {
   float sum = 0.0;
   for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    sum += array[i];
   }
    return sum/float(array.length());
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    float a1[] = float[](1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.1);
    float a2[] = float[](1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2);
    float av = average(a1)+average(a2);
    fragColor = vec4(av,0.0,0.0,0.0);
}
```

Is it possible to define a function that accepts an array parameter of any size, instead of defining a different function for each size?

Comment: Related: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/5323/dynamic-array-in-glsl

Comment: @3Dave It doesn't need to be dynamic. It only needs to accept a fixed-size parameter with any size.

Comment: Simplest thing that comes to mind is to pick an upper bound and pass in the array as well as a length. I don't have a way to test that on my phone, but it's simple. I'm not sure if the compiler will allow it.